# How to navigate from a screen in stack navigator to the Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

My project structure looks like this
Tab navigator
|-Tab1
|-Tab2
    |-stack navigator
          |-login
              |
             screen1
              |
             screen2
               |
             screen3
|-Tab3
|-Tab4
I am new to react native. I am trying to navigate from a screen1 in stack navigator to my Tab1. I am not able to navigate. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: [Read This](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html)  hope it'll help you

Comment: Thank you, Kishan Gujarati. That worked.

Comment: Wlcm... Happy coding